# flashing a rom on a different samsung note model

Tags: samsung, rom-flashing, samsung-galaxy-note-4

i have recently bought a Samsung note 4 sm-g910H  (at least that what it says in the settings)  but upon opening it up i noticed that the USB module had sm-n910F typed on its ribbon connector ,and after lifting up the motherboard i noticed sm-n910C typed on the motherboard , is THIS normal , and if it is !! could i possibly flash a n910C ROM on the device because i am having issues with all sorts of connectivity on the device 
1- Bluetooth restarting itself every like 5-15 minutes only when  connected to a WiFi network.
2-error when trying to tether my phone to a computer.
3-extremely weak reception.

thanks in advance.:)

Comment: Or you have the wrong ROM on it to start with? You say you have problems....

Comment: well , that`s what i am trying to figure out . when i bought the phone it had sm-910H model on it and still has but when i opened the phone i saw "sm-n910C"